# "deselectRow" doesn't animate if using "popViewController"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Swift 5, Xcode 10

My app uses two `ViewControllers`:

1. VC1, `UITableView`, clicking on a cell calls
2. VC2, displays further information about a cell with the default `UINavigationBarItem` "back" button on the top left and an addition "save" button at the bottom

The "save" buttons saves the changes made. To go back to the VC2, you can either click on the "back" button or save the changes, which also automatically loads VC2 using:

```
@IBAction func onClickSave(_ sender: Any) {
    //Save changes
    delegate?.passRowSavedBack(true) //Tell VC1 that changes were saved
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

If I go back using the `UINavigationBarItem` "back" button, the cell also keeps its selection color for a second, then removes it (like in the iOS "Contacts" app) using this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    myTableView.deselectRow(at: mylastRowPickedIndex!, animated: true)
}
```

Example [gif](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2016/05/Default-Deselection.gif).

The problem is: If I go back with the "Save" button, this code is called too but there's no animation.

My guess is that `popViewController` takes longer to go back than whatever the "back" button calls, so the animation is played but you don't "arrive" in time to see it.

But how do I fix this? Is there a different way to go back to VC1 through the "Save" button (without removing the default "back" button!) that still plays the animation?

**Edit:** What I'm doing exactly:

1. In VC2: Save the changes
2. Tell VC1 that they were saved with a delegate (check 1st code above):

```
protocol PassingProtocol {
    func passRowSavedBack(_ valueSent: Bool)
}
```

3. Go back to VC1 using `popViewController` (check 1st code above)
4. In VC1: `deselectRow` in `viewWillAppear` (check 2nd code above)
5. `rowsSaved[lastRowPicked] = true`, so it can add an `accessoryType` in here:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = (rowsSaved[indexPath.row]==true) ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

6. `myTableView.reloadData()` - so it displays the new checkmark

Comment: In the `onClickSave` action, is there async tasks going on the "//Save changes, then" part?

Comment: did you try with  viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) instead of viewWillAppear??

Comment: @AhmadF No async tasks going on, no (haven't come to that yet). It's calling the switch right after it's done saving on the main thread.

Comment: @m1sh0 Just did. With the "back" button the animation now starts later (because it doesn't start until the view is actually loaded) but it still doesn't show if I go back with the "save" button. I also let it output `mylastRowPickedIndex` - it's the same for both.

Comment: In fact, I test it on my project and it is okay, with one small difference I just store the row not the IndexPath. I don't believe this is the problem I think it can be in your onClickSave function. Is it possible if you have some notification or something that triggers a reload table when you save the data?

Comment: @m1sh0 I store the number of the row too, additional to the IndexPath, and tested creating an IndexPath out of it but the problem's still there. Yes, I do reload the table: If the data is saved in VC2, I use a `delegate` (`protocol PassingProtocol {func passRowSavedBack(_ valueSent: Bool)}`) to set a bool in VC1 that `myLastRowPicked` was saved. After `deselectRow` (in `viewWillAppear`) I check if the bool was set, give that row a "checkmark" (`accessoryType`, I set a bool in an arrow for that row) and reload the table.

Comment: hmm can you edit your question and add what you are doing because like this is hard to understand you

Comment: @m1sh0 Okay, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I think I understand what is the problem.

You are calling `myTableView.reloadData()` and this is the problem with deselecting animation.

You can move `myTableView.reloadData()` in viewDidAppear() and everything will be okay.

Comment: You're right, moving it to `viewDidAppear` works, thanks. Unfortunately this reloads the table when it's already visible. :/ If I use the default "back" button it works even with `viewWillAppear`, so something else has to be missing too. Is there maybe any other type of "pop" that you can use with a navigation controller instead of `popViewController`? Something that works exactly like the default?

Comment: they are the same things, your back button doing the same thing as poViewController. I don't know your code but what you need to do is in func passRowSavedBack(_ valueSent: Bool) to save if you need to refresh and on viewDidAppear to check and refresh if it is needed. (You also can mark my answer as correct one if you think it is :) )

Comment: If the "back" button and "pop" do the exact same thing, I don't understand why it's working with the former but not with the latter. The saving and `passRowSavedBack` are done before VC1 even starts to replace VC2, so in the end the loading process should be the same, no matter which button I use to go back (I don't distinguish in VC1), but it looks like there's still a difference.

Comment: Not sure, if I have the full picture maybe I can see what is the problem. One possible explanation: In animations, if you want to rotate something on 360 you need to do it in 2 steps of 180 because if you do it directly on 360 the view will not move. Still, I don't believe this is the case with reloading data but without all the information it is hard to debug.

Comment: I understand why your example would/wouldn't work but `deselectRow` isn't even an animation I have any control over - I tell it to animate, that's it, but it behaves like it's set to not animate. If you move everything in your test to `viewWillAppear` and use the "pop" func, does it still animate for you? `if I have the full picture maybe I can see what is the problem` - what do you need exactly?

Comment: If I have tableView.reloadData() in viewWilAppear, there is no difference if I click back or popViewController I don't see the animation. I don't know how it is possible to work for you on back. there is something that I don't know. I need the all swift file of VC1 and VC2.

Comment: Hm, that's really weird! Did you maybe add a special navigation bar or navigation bar item? Sorry, can't post the whole files.

Comment: nope everything is normal for me it works without to call tableView.deselect and in my viewWillAppear I passing animated instead of always true. I test with the last two things but again can't reproduce your state to have different behavior on the back and normal popViewController maybe the difference is what are you doing in passRowSavedBack. Can you test to skip this method?

Comment: Are you using a `TableViewController` or a normal `ViewController`? I'm using the normal kind but if you're using the "Table" one, then you don't have to call `deselect` because it does it automatically (not sure if it animates it though).

Comment: I tested it: Without `delegate`, `lastRowSaved` is always `false`, `reloadData` isn't called in `willAppear` and there's always an animation. If I set `lastRowSaved = true` every time, which also calls `reloadData` every time, there's no animation for either pop. So it is reloading that's causing this. Having the reload happen in `didAppear` probably works because it's giving the animation enough time to finish (?) before the table is reloaded. Looks like I'm either going to need a completion handler or just have to keep the reload in `didAppear`... Thanks for your help and thanks for testing!

Comment: I test it with UITableViewController, I think you don't have a problem to move it in viewDidAppear and add check for lastRowSaved